# org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: syntax error at or near "-"

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc

I have a PostreSQL database which I am trying to access with a Java app. When it comes to the following code:

```
public class UserRepo {

    private String baseQuery = "SELECT * FROM bank-console.user_credentials ";


    public Optional<UserInfo> findUserByCredentials(String username, String password) {

        Optional<UserInfo> _user = Optional.empty();

        try (Connection conn = ConnectionFactory.getInstance().getConnection()){
            String sql =  baseQuery +
                    "WHERE username = ? AND password = ?";
            PreparedStatement pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
            pstmt.setString(1, username);
            pstmt.setString(2, password);

            ResultSet rs = pstmt.executeQuery();

            _user = mapResultSet(rs).stream().findFirst();

        } catch (SQLException sqle) {
            sqle.printStackTrace();
        }

        return _user;
    }
```

It throws the error message exactly as the question title. When I take the text of the baseQuery and the String sql and enter them in my PostgreSQL app exactly (replacing the question marks with actual values), it retrieves the table perfectly. Where is the syntax error here?

My pom file contains

```
<dependency>
      <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
      <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
      <version>42.2.12</version>
 </dependency>
```

Comment: Put double-quotes around the schema name like this `"bank-console".user_credentials`.  You should not have put a hyphen in an identifier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In response to @Mike Organek's comment, the answer is that bank-console should not have a hyphen. Using double-quotes did not work because the baseQuery is already within double quotes. Single-quotes was a syntax error in itself. So what worked was to change bank-console to bankconsole. My SQL app allowed me to do that without losing the tables. Then just change the baseQuery accordingly.